# Cookie not sent to API

Tags: express, cookies, credentials

I am trying to access a cookie in my Apollo-Server-Express API from a next.js application. Unfortunately, the cookie doesn't seem to be sent along with my fetch request:

```js
export const employeeSessionFetch = async (
  apiUrl: string,
) => {
  const data = await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `query {
        employeeSession {
          id
          employee_id
        }
      }`,
    }),
  });
  return data;
};
```

I am not getting any CORS errors, and otherwise, requests work fine. The domain of the cookie is the same as the api server's.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I was doing this request from getServerSideProps, which is server-side, so the cookies were unsurprisingly not available there. I then transferred that request to a useEffect in my component and everything worked as expected.